# Blur Background for iOS14 Widgets

Tags: swift, swiftui, background, widget, ios14

I've created some iOS14 Widgets and set a Rectangle with a custom Image as Background for it.
It have a corner Radius and a padding to all sides.

The Result is a black Background behind my custom Background and I don't know how to make it blur like other Widgets (for example the Shortcuts Widget you see in the picture at the bottom).

Has anyone an idea what I can do?

[image]

Update:

Ok I figured out that you can change the background color in the Widget struct itself. A nice way is to set the colors you want in Assets Catalog from the Widget -> WidgetBackground and add the following code in the struct:

```
@main
struct CoreDataWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "CoreDataWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: HomeWidgetTimeline()) { entry in
            HomeWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
                .background(Color("WidgetBackground")) // <- this line

        }
        .configurationDisplayName("OhMyMoney")
        .description("You want to know your current Money and add Expenses quickly with one Touch? \nThen use this Widget!".localized())
        .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall, .systemMedium, .systemLarge])
    }
}
```

But is there a way to make the background transparent like the Shortcuts Widget from the picture above?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible :(

> 3rd Party Apps cannot use blurred backgrounds for their Widgets

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655990